# PHP pthreads namespace passing issue

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads, xdebug

I faced a problem developing application with pthreads support. If I don't call pthreads function `start()` everything work as planned. But with calling `start()` function, the namespaces gets broken (I think so) and my class does nothing. Here is sample:

```
namespace LF\Utility;
use LF\Utility\Callme;

class Threaded extends \Thread {

    public function __construct(){
        //Constructor stuff
    }

    public function run(){
        echo "in thread";
        $test = new Callme(1);
    }
}
```

And the Callme:

```
namespace LF\Utility;

class Callme {

    public function __construct($val)
    {
        echo "num: " . $val;
    }

}
```

Using `$thread->run()` is giving right result, calling `$thread->start()` is not calling `Callme` constructor. Second thing is that I can't debug threaded part of code with xDebug, is there some easy way to do so?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works fine for me.

```
<?php
namespace LF\Utility;

require_once 'callme.php';

use LF\Utility\Callme;

class Threaded extends \Thread {

    public function __construct(){
        //Constructor stuff
    }

    public function run(){
        echo "in thread" . PHP_EOL;
        $test = new Callme(1);
    }
}

$t = new Threaded();
$t->start();
```

How are you loading the "Callme" class in the main class? Autoloader? Or something else? Please check that.

Comment: I am loading that class using traits, I don't want to use `require`/`requre_once` as it has to work with `use` calls, otherwise I am losing all other classes already loaded or I have to call them with ridiculous way eg. `base\LF\Profile\ClassName`

Comment: Oh, as I wrote - it works with $t->run(), just start() is causing this issues.

Comment: @Trouble It works fine with start() as you can see from my code.

Comment: you need to set your autoloader in ::run